# How could I use Bluetooth 2.1 programmatically? (with iPhone4)

Tags: ios, bluetooth

*Environment:* iPhone4(Bluetooth 2.1) and Samsung Galaxy S3(Bluetooth 4.0).

*Needs:* I want to know that how to code **advertising with Bluetooth 2.1**. Could I use `CoreBluetooth`?

*Details:* (peripheral) iPhone4 advertises "some data" through Bluetooth 2.1, and (central) Galaxy S3 catches not only the basic information of iPhone4 but also the "some data" from iPhone4.

I'm new in iOS programming. I'll be grateful for any answer.

Thank you.

*Followings are added*

[image]

> *Screenshot on Galaxy S3*

iOS doesn't need to search anything. I've already seen that iPhone4 cannot search any android devices. I just want to know about peripheral iOS and central android. The fact is Galaxy S3 could find iPhone4, so I wondered it might be possible for Galaxy S3 to get a little more data packet with the device's name while searching devices via bluetooth. And if yes, I want to know how to code that in iOS side.

Comment: You need to use the external connectivity framework to communication with bt 2.1 devices but those devices need to be MFi certified, so there is no chance you will be able to communicate between an iPhone 4 and a galaxy S3. If you have a 4s or later then you can use Core Bluetooth with an app on each device

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I didn't communicate well. I don't need whole connection, but the advertising packets. As you know, while searching other devices via bluetooth, central device gets **basic information** about other devices. I need just advertise my data on the **basic information** packets. Isn't it possible? @Paulw11

Comment: An iPhone 4 doesn't have BLE support so there is nothing you can do as far as Bluetooth is concerned

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/Ls5GU7L.png)
I found that I could search iPhone4 on Galaxy S3. You can see that Galaxy S3 can search the iPhone4 device and get the device name. It means that Galaxy S3 get **some information(containing device's name)** while searching. What only I need is to send a string via the **some information**. Could Galaxy S3 get not only device's name but also the string "foobar". Am I saying right? Sorry for question again. @Paulw11

Comment: There are no publicly accessible APIs on iOS that will let you discover Bluetooth devices aside from CoreBluetooth and that needs Bluetooth low energy

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. iOS doesn't need to search anything. I've already seen that iPhone4 cannot search any android devices. I just want to know about peripheral iOS and central android. The fact is Galaxy S3 could find iPhone4, so I wondered it might be possible for Galaxy S3 to get a little more data packet with the device's name while searching devices via bluetooth. And if yes, I want to know how to code that in iOS side. I'm so sorry for my English, and so thank you for your fast reply. It's my last question. @Paulw11